# Below code does repeat the same hotfix for all the servers even though that was not installed

Tags: powershell

I got a script which should collect the list of hotfixes from a number of servers. The names/addresses of the servers can be found in a text file. The final result should be CSV listing the hotfixes for each server.

The problem with the below code is that it lists the same hotfix for every server, though that hotfix isn't installed on every server. What's the Error in my approach?

```
$Servers = Get-Content 'C:\temp\Servers.txt'

$gg = foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    Try {
        $Hotfix = Get-Hotfix -computername $Server | Where {$_.hotfixid -eq 'KBXXXXXX' -or  $_.hotfixid -eq 'KBXXXXXX' -or $_.hotfixid -eq 'KBXXXXXX'} -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch {
        #Write-host "Unable to reach the Server " $Server
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message;
        Continue
    }
    $HotfixID = $Hotfix.HotFixID;
    $NotFound = "NotFound";
    " " | Select-Object -Property @{N="Server_Name";E={$Server}}, @{N="HotFixID";E={
        if ($HotfixID -eq $null) {
            Return $ErrorMessage
        }
        elseif ($HotfixID -ne $null -and $ErrorMessage -eq $null) {
            Return $HotfixID
        }
        elseif ($HotfixID -eq $null -and $ErrorMessage -eq $null) {
            Return $NotFound
        }}}
}
$gg | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation 'C:\Temp\Output.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

You current code has multiple different properties that you might want to check up on. As it is, it shouldn't list the same errors. It's likely that it's either not the code you actually ran or that you ran code before it that did some setup. Here's a list of flaws with this code:

- With your current approach you will skip a server if there is an error reading the list of hotfixes. Meanwhile you later on try to act on `$ErrorMessage` which is going to be `$null` for every successful server.
- Your `Select-Object` for the HotFix is needlessly complicated. It has two cases which are literally the same so you will never have `$NotFound` returned. In addition while an expression is supported, for clarity could/should favor a simple variable assignment like you did with the `Server_Name` property.
- [`Get-HotFix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-hotfix) supports a `-Id` switch which accepts an array of `HotFixID` (basically the KB name) which might improve performance. So you could just do:

  ```
  $hotfixes = Get-HotFix -Id KB4012212,KB4012215,KBDoesNotExist -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Stop
  ```
- The data returned by `Get-HotFix` include a property named `PSComputer` which seems to indicate the source of the data. The parameter to supply a computer name actually also accepts an array of strings as a parameter. As such you could further improve the above command to be:

  ```
  $hotfixes = Get-HotFix -Id KB4012212,KB4012215,KBDoesNotExist -ComputerName "server01.example.com","server02.example.com" -ErrorAction Stop
  ```

  With this you would later on just need to run `Select-Object` on `$hotfixes` and could directly pipe to the `Export-CSV` cmdlet.

I don't have the infrastructure to test it but a final solution could look like this:

```
$servers = Get-Content 'C:\temp\Servers.txt'
$hotfixes = Get-HotFix -Id KB4012212,KB4012215,KBDoesNotExist -ComputerName "server01.example.com","server02.example.com"
$hotfixes = $hotfixes | Select-Object -Property @{Name="Server_Name";Expression={$_.PSComputerName}}, @{Name="HotFixID"; Expression={$_.HotFixID}}
$hotfixes | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation 'C:\Temp\Output.csv'
```

A downside here is that it doesn't handle errors while trying to connect to the server(s) and won't include servers that don't have any of the specified hotfixes. For that kind of information you would need to use a loop.

```
$servers = Get-Content 'C:\temp\s.txt'
$servers | ForEach-Object{
    $server = $_
    $serverError = $null;

    try{
        $hotfixes = Get-HotFix -Id KB4012212,KB4012215,KBDoesNotExist -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Stop
    }catch{
        $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $serverError = " " | Select-Object -Property @{Name="Server_Name";Expression={$server}}, @{Name="HotFixID"; Expression={$errorMessage}}

    }

    if($serverError -ne $null){
        $serverError
    }else{
        $hotfixes = $hotfixes | Select-Object -Property @{Name="Server_Name";Expression={$_.PSComputerName}}, @{Name="HotFixID"; Expression={$_.HotFixID}}
        $hotfixes
    }
} | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

In theory this could be simplified further as `$serverError` would be `$null` which shouldn't generate an output line.

The KBs are just copied from an article. No idea if they would exist or not, they're just there to illustrate.